# Редактор текста на сайте, с помощью html, css, javascript

Tags: html, javascript, css

Начал учиться веб-разработке, делаю сайт и на нем по плану будет много текста, не хочется вводить текст прямо в файлах html, может быть есть готовые решения, кроме cms?

Comment: Есть, phpmyadmin

Comment: А wysiwyg-редакторы чем не устраивают?

Comment: Хочется именно понять работу всех операторов, тегов, свойств, как можно меньше автоматизации, phpadmin -он на ПэХаПэ - его учить не охота, хочется какой-нибудь скриптик на javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всех туда посылаю и тебя тоже [ВОТ СЮДА](http://imperavi.com/redactor/)
Нормальный редактор. минимальный вес и все просто. удобен и легок, что еще нужно?

Answer (score 0):

Насколько готовым должно быть решение? Вот, есть [wheat](https://github.com/creationix/wheat) для node.js -- его идея в том, что статьи пишут markdown-синтаксисом и хранят в текстовых файлах (под контролем git) а движок их преобразует в html.

Можно самому написать javascript-код, который запрашивает с сервера текстовые файлы и отображает их на странице.

Comment: Человек только учится верстать, а вы ему node.js/git

Comment: Я же не хаскель предлагаю. Про VCS вообще и гит с гитхабом в частности надо знать обязательно, без них никуда. А node.js -- достаточно простая штука. У wheat,правда, код довольно замороченный, но если его не читать, а просто поставить, будет довольно легко.

Comment: Я с вам согласен, git/github - наше все, но все же нужно быть последовательным. Если бы не умея программировать и толком верстать, я бы начал тыкать git, я бы наверное стал финансистом или менеджером.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте [tinymce](http://www.tinymce.com/).